# Scrape and section data frame based on <strong> tags from rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a string of text scraped from a website using rvest. However, the text is broken up into sections that are not defined by heading tags in the HTML. Instead, they are just classified with  tags.

For example, the tag structure looks like

```
<div class="field-docs-content">
<p><strong>Title 1</strong></p>
<p> some sentences, some lines</p>
<p> some sentences, some lines</p>
<p> some sentences, some lines</p>
<p><strong>Another Title 2</strong></p>
<p> some sentences, some lines</p>
<p> some sentences, some lines</p>
<p> some sentences, some lines</p>
</div>
```

If I just scraped in `rvest` by 'field-docs-content', I would get a string such that

```
Title 1 some sentences, some lines some sentences, some lines some sentences, some lines Another Title 2 some sentences, some lines some sentences, some lines some sentences, some lines
```

which, if I were to convert that to a data frame, it would return one cell with all this text

What I want is a data frame with 2 cells such that the above string is broken by the titles that were labeled with the  tags like:

```
Title 1 some sentences, some lines some sentences, some lines some sentences, some lines 
Another Title 2 some sentences, some lines some sentences, some lines some sentences, some lines
```

Directly, what I am looking for is

- a data frame with cells broken at the start of the string with a <strong. tag
- All the p tags under those strong tagged "headings" to be joined together instead of breaking up

My current scrape code looks like

```
webpage <- read_html(url)
data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.field-docs-content') 
data <- html_text(data_html)
head(data)
```

I could replace '.field-docs-content' with 'strong' but it would not break up the sentences in the p tags below it.

A good URL example of this in the wild is: https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/2016-democratic-party-platform

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using xpath syntax to pick out the correct elements, and `mapply` to put them in a tibble:

```r
library(rvest)

url   <- "https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/2016-democratic-party-platform"

page  <-  read_html(url) 

heads <-  page %>%
          html_nodes(xpath = "//p/strong/parent::p") %>% 
          html_text()

all_p <-  page %>%
          html_nodes(xpath = "//p") %>% 
          html_text()

start <-  match(heads, all_p)
end   <-  c(start[-1], length(all_p))

result <- as_tibble(do.call(rbind, mapply(function(a, b, h) 
          {
            data.frame(header = h, body = paste(all_p[(a + 1):b], collapse = "\n"))
          }, a = start, b = end, h = heads, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))
```

Which gives you:

```
result
#> # A tibble: 15 x 2
#>    header                                     body                                    
#>    <chr>                                      <chr>                                   
#>  1 Preamble                                   "In 2016, Democrats meet in Philadelphi~
#>  2 Raise Incomes and Restore Economic Securi~ "Democrats believe we must break down a~
#>  3 Create Good-Paying Jobs                    "Democrats know that nothing is more im~
#>  4 Fight for Economic Fairness and Against I~ "Democrats believe that today's extreme~
#>  5 Bring Americans Together and Remove Barri~ "Democrats believe that everyone deserv~
#>  6 Protect Voting Rights, Fix Our Campaign F~ "Democrats know that Americans' right t~
#>  7 Combat Climate Change, Build a Clean Ener~ "Climate change is an urgent threat and~
#>  8 Provide Quality and Affordable Education   "Democrats know that every child, no ma~
#>  9 Ensure the Health and Safety of All Ameri~ "Democrats have been fighting to secure~
#> 10 Principled Leadership                      "Democrats believe that America must le~
#> 11 Support Our Troops and Keep Faith with Ou~ "Democrats believe America must continu~
#> 12 Confront Global Threats                    "Democrats will protect our country. We~
#> 13 Protect Our Values                         "Our values of inclusion and tolerance ~
#> 14 A Leader in the World                      "American leadership is essential to ke~
#> 15 The American Presidency ProjectJohn Wooll~ "Twitter Facebook\nCopyright © The Amer~
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to treat it like other problems you might solve with tidyverse:

```r
  
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

url <- "https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/2016-democratic-party-platform"
webpage <- read_html(url)

headers <- 
webpage %>% 
  html_nodes(".field-docs-content strong") %>% 
  html_text()

body <- webpage %>% 
  html_nodes(".field-docs-content p") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  tibble(body_text = .)

body %>%
  mutate(
    headers = case_when(body_text %in% headers ~ body_text)
    ) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(headers) %>% 
  filter(headers != body_text) %>% 
  group_by(headers) %>% 
  summarise(body_text = paste(body_text, collapse = " "))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 14 x 2
#>    headers                                body_text                             
#>    <chr>                                  <chr>                                 
#>  1 A Leader in the World                  "American leadership is essential to …
#>  2 Bring Americans Together and Remove B… "Democrats believe that everyone dese…
#>  3 Combat Climate Change, Build a Clean … "Climate change is an urgent threat a…
#>  4 Confront Global Threats                "Democrats will protect our country. …
#>  5 Create Good-Paying Jobs                "Democrats know that nothing is more …
#>  6 Ensure the Health and Safety of All A… "Democrats have been fighting to secu…
#>  7 Fight for Economic Fairness and Again… "Democrats believe that today's extre…
#>  8 Preamble                               "In 2016, Democrats meet in Philadelp…
#>  9 Principled Leadership                  "Democrats believe that America must …
#> 10 Protect Our Values                     "Our values of inclusion and toleranc…
#> 11 Protect Voting Rights, Fix Our Campai… "Democrats know that Americans' right…
#> 12 Provide Quality and Affordable Educat… "Democrats know that every child, no …
#> 13 Raise Incomes and Restore Economic Se… "Democrats believe we must break down…
#> 14 Support Our Troops and Keep Faith wit… "Democrats believe America must conti…
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach to isolate the bold section headers using `html_nodes`:

```
full <- data_html %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text()

headers <- data_html %>% html_nodes("strong") %>% html_text()
```

Then it's just a matter of organizing the text into the structure you want. The way you describe it sounds like a vector, which you could put into a dataframe if you want. Here's one way to create of vector where elements are broken up by bold header

```
ids <- which(full %in% headers) # starting position of section

ids2 <- ids + c(diff(ids), length(full) - tail(ids, 1) + 1) - 1 # ending position of section

vec <- rep(NA, length(ids)) # Create empty vector for destination values
for(i in 1:(length(ids))) {
  vals = ids[i]:ids2[i]
  vec[i] = paste(full[vals], collapse = " ")
}
```